# Nginx RTMP with InstagramLive-PHP not working

Tags: php, c++, nginx, rtmp

I wonder if I am going about this wrong. So the two libraries I am using are:
1. https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module
2. https://github.com/JRoy/InstagramLive-PHP

The Nginx RTMP module works fine and I am able to stream to everything from Facebook to Twitch but I cant seem to get this to work with the InstagramLive library. I am using the below format on the nginx.conf file based on the stream key and URL i receive after I run the InstagramLive library:

```
rtmp {
        server {
                listen 1935;
                chunk_size 4096;

                application live {
                        live on;
                        record off;
                        push rtmp://live-upload.instagram.com:80/rtmp/<key>;
                }
        }
}
```

When I start the OBS stream however, the Instagram account shows its live but doesnt load up the video and an error saying timed out appears after sometime. I assume there is a problem with the scaling/resolution and appreciate if someone can help out.

UPDATE:

So I got it to stream to Instagram but there seemed to be a scaling issue when directly streaming so was trying to use ffmpeg to workaround. Came up with this code below:

```
rtmp {
        server {
                listen 1935;
                chunk_size 4096;

                application live {
                    live on;
                    record off;

                    allow publish all;
                    allow play all;

                    push rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/youtube;

                    exec ffmpeg -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/$name -threads 1 -vcodec flv -acodec copy -s 1280x720 -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/youtube;

                }

                application instagram {
                    live on;
                    record off;

                    push rtmp://live-upload.instagram.com:80/rtmp/KEY;
                }

                application youtube {
                    live on;
                    record off;

                    push rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/KEY;
                }

        }
}
```

Somehow now again the Instagram video doesnt load, Youtube or any other streams I include will work though.

Answer (score 0):

Instagram uses secure rtmp (rtmps://...) but unfortunately nginx-rtmp module does not support rtmps. you can use a 3rd-party (for example you can use stunnel) program to do the job:

```
#nginx.conf
application live{
    push  rtmp://127.0.0.1:19350/rtmp/{your-insta-stream-key}
}
```

And in the stunnel configuration file:

```
#stunnel.conf
pid=/tmp/stunnel/stunnel.pid
output = /tmp/stunnel/stunnel.log
[insta-live]
client = yes
accept = 127.0.0.1:19350
connect = live-upload.instagram.com:443
```

Do not forget to open port 19350 on your server